# How to log in pure kotlin code ( can't use Log.v)

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, logging, module

I am using Clean architecture in android project which consist of different module with UseCase module that has no android sdk dependencies.thus can't have access to Log.v or Log.i ....
how can i preview and log what's in a variable ,is there a way to print to console , using System.out.print or simply println...how can i visualize that output in the console ?

Comment: You can directly use `println()`

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://proandroiddev.com/logging-in-a-multi-module-android-project-7294382e59fa